# IE8 session expires in few seconds after logging in

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, session, browser, internet-explorer-8

I am facing an issue with IE8 browser. The following is the workflow

```
User clicks on login in the site -> 
Taken to the intranet portal to login (SSO) -> 
User logs in successfully and gets back to the site -> 
After few seconds, the session expires and user gets logged out on the next request.
```

I cannot find this in all IE8 browsers. I hope there should be some security/privacy/advanced setting which controls this.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What are you using to associate the session with the client?

Comment: I am storing session in cookies. Sorry if i got your question wrong.

Comment: Have you debugged the session validity with a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/)?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347806/csrfguard-request-token-does-not-match-session-token

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a problem with clock settings and time zones? Maybe the expiry time is calculated by javascript on the client and then checked against time on the server?  If the client and server clocks are different you may see this kind of problem.  Also beware that some systems give timestamps in milliseconds.

Comment: Is there a setting where we can manually set cookie expiration time in  IE8 browser? We don't expire based on time with our code.