# CSRFGuard - request token does not match session token

Tags: csrf, owasp, csrf-protection

I am trying to incorporate the CSRFGuard library in order to rectify some CSRF vulnerabilties in an application. However after configuring as specified [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFGuard_3_User_Manual) I am now getting the below messages in the log, when I navigate the application:

```
WARNING: potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:<anonymous>, ip:169.xx.x.xxx, uri:/myapp/MyAction, error:request token does not match session token)
```

Through including the:

```
<script src="/sui/JavaScriptServlet"></script>
```

On my `main.jsp` page the links have all been built incorporating the `CSRFGuard` `token`, e.g.

```
......./myapp/MyAction?CSRFTOKEN=BNY8-3H84-6SRR-RJXM-KMCH-KLLD-1W45-M18N
```

So I am unable to understand what I'm doing wrong that could cause the links to pass a token other than the expected value.

Please let me know if any additional information would make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles across a similar issue:

Turned out that accessing the app using IE wasn't passing a token to an AJAX call, this would in turn result in the tokens being refreshed but the links in the already rendered page remained, causing the mismatch when clicked.

Found out the issue by building CSRFGuard myself from source and adding extra logging.

Comment: how did you add extra logging in CSRF Guard... can you please give me some details?

Comment: hey @Mike, i just added a few getLogger().log() entries in the CsrfGuard class (mostly in the verifyAjaxToken and verifyPageToken methods. Logged things including the token value from the request and the token from the session to make it more obvious to compare

Comment: Thanks @t_barbz .. actually in my case, CSRF Guard is not injecting token for every request it is only injecting token for first request. Any idea why it is not injecting... can you help on that...Thanks.

Comment: Not sure tbh sorry, I only looked into CSRFGuard briefly as it didnt work correctly on the older browser versions that I had to support. Make sure you are using a recent version, i know originally i had to build CSRFGuard from source to avoid some known bugs, but that might have been fixed now.

Comment: @Mike - Hi Mike, few days back I have started to implement `CSRGGuard` (am using `3.1.0` csrfguard dependency in pom.xml instead of using source code)  into my project & I am facing same issue. I hope you have some workaround on this  so can you please share yours ideas how it will get fix. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @t_barbz : Hi t_barbz, exactly I have been facing same issue while implementing `CSRFGuard` to my application so I have commented these lines of code `else if (!tokenFromSession.equals(tokenFromRequest))` in `private void verifySessionToken(HttpServletRequest request) throws CsrfGuardException ` method

Comment: And I made `org.owasp.csrfguard.TokenPerPage=false` but now it looks not make any sense to me because per page token validation will not happen with this change by csrfguard & as I commented session level token verification as in above comment  also will not happen. Now csrfguard will only check the token as part of request url or request data if request contains form data `tokenFromRequest == null || tokenFromRequest.isEmpty()`

Comment: @t_barbz : The same happening in my case too as you comments as part of yours answer like `tokens being refreshed but the links in the already rendered page remained, causing the mismatch when clicked.` And I have been using `<groupId>org.owasp</groupId> <artifactId>csrfguard</artifactId> <version>3.1.0</version>` still no use I mean looks OWASP team not have been updated this code as you said one of above yours comment.

Comment: @t_barbz : I am very glad to you if you suggest anything on this.

Answer (score 0):

The primefaces commandlink and commandbutton seem to cause the csrfguard javascript to malfunction, if you have use these two component with ajax set to true (which is the default), it can prevent the token being injected after the ajax call

Answer (score -1):

One of the possible fixes is to change the following 2 lines in Owasp.CsrfGuard.js file.

Change

```
 function injectTokenForm(form, tokenName, tokenValue, pageTokens) {
    var action = form.attribute("action");
```

To

```
 function injectTokenForm(form, tokenName, tokenValue, pageTokens) {
    var action = form.attributes["action"].value;
```

AND

Change

```
 function injectTokenAttribute(element, attr, tokenName, tokenValue, pageTokens) {

    location = element.getAttribute(attr);
```

To

```
 function injectTokenAttribute(element, attr, tokenName, tokenValue, pageTokens) {
    var location = null;
    if (attr == "action") {
        location = element.attributes[attr].value;

    } else {
        location = element.getAttribute(attr);
    }
```

Comment: Are you able to explain a bit more about what this fixes specifically please and how?  Thanks

Comment: Part of the answer seems to be that IE doesn’t like the former if you have a form field named action. Source http://www.selikoff.net/2013/02/09/csrf-extending-the-owasp-solution-interesting-javascript-bug/